# AWS event notifications for single object in a bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudtrail

I see that we can add event notifications for a bucket in S3. Is it possible to add event notifications for just a particular object in a bucket? For eg file hello.txt in my bucket/folder/hello.txt

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_rRlnSw_5s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add a prefix, which is the folder name and a suffix which is the file type.